# How would I remove an item from a list of tuples

Tags: python

I am collecting the information located in the information box on Wikipedia. I am storing the data in a list.  However, the first span tag I retrieve stores an image. I want to remove the image from the list.

```
    for my_tables in my_table:
    row1 = my_table.find_all('th',{'scope':'row'})

    row2 = my_table.find_all('td')

    for my_tables in my_table.find_all('td'):

    grab_text2 = (my_tables.text, my_tables.next_sibling)

    row2_list.append(grab_text2)

    print (row2_list)
```

The current output is  :

```
[('', None), 
('11 August 1902\xa0(1902-08-11)Paris, France', None), 
('29 July 1991(1991-07-29) (aged\xa088)Paris, France', None), 
('\xa0France', None), ('\xa0French Army', None), ('1921-1959', None), 
('General de brigade', None), 
('Mobile Group 2Mobile Group 1Operational Group North-West', None), 
('World War IIFirst Indochina War*Battle of Dien Bien Phu', None)]
```

The ' ('', None) ' being the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove any blank items it can be done with a simple list comprehension

```
row2_new = [item for item in row2_list if item[0]]
```

row2_new will now contain

```
[('11 August 1902\xa0(1902-08-11)Paris, France', None), ('29 July 1991(1991-07-29) (aged\xa088)Paris, France', None), ('\xa0France', None), ('\xa0French Army', None), ('1921-1959', None), ('General de brigade', None), ('Mobile Group 2Mobile Group 1Operational Group North-West', None), ('World War IIFirst Indochina War*Battle of Dien Bien Phu', None)]
```

If you just want to remove the first element then a simple slicing operation will do.

```
row2_new = row2_list[1:]
```